# Map date column to unique sequential numbers starting from 1 in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a column of dates in a dataframe, where each of the dates usually repeats a couple of times. Here is an example of my dataframe, which also has the names of some sports teams in other columns:

```
dput(mydf)
structure(list(date_game = structure(c(15643, 15643, 15643, 15644, 
15644, 15644, 15646, 15646), class = "Date"), team_id = c("WAS", 
"CLE", "LAL", "SAC", "CHI", "DET", "BOS", "MIL"), fran_id = c("Wizards", 
"Cavaliers", "Lakers", "Kings", "Bulls", "Pistons", "Celtics", 
"Bucks")), .Names = c("date_game", "team_id", "fran_id"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 29L, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

In this case, mydf has 3 unique dates, and skips a date as well. My full dataframe has hundreds of unique dates. For this example, I am interested in adding a new column to the dataframe (call it date_number), that would look like this:

```
mydf
    date_game team_id   fran_id  date_number
1  2012-10-30     WAS   Wizards            1
2  2012-10-30     CLE Cavaliers            1
3  2012-10-30     LAL    Lakers            1
7  2012-10-31     SAC     Kings            2
8  2012-10-31     CHI     Bulls            2
9  2012-10-31     DET   Pistons            2
29 2012-11-02     BOS   Celtics            3
30 2012-11-02     MIL     Bucks            3
```

Like the title says - starting with 1 in the date_number column, I would like increasing, sequential numbers for the dates. The key part of this is that the column is sequential, even if certain dates are missing. Although 11-01 is not there, 11-02 still gets set to 3, not 4.

Any thoughts on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
mydf$date_number = as.integer(as.factor(mydf$date_game))
```

Comment: Voted this the accepted answer because it is the simplest, which is what I value most, but the other answers were good too

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `rleid` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, date_number := rleid(date_game)]
```

**Result:**

```
> df
    date_game team_id   fran_id date_number
1: 2012-10-30     WAS   Wizards           1
2: 2012-10-30     CLE Cavaliers           1
3: 2012-10-30     LAL    Lakers           1
4: 2012-10-31     SAC     Kings           2
5: 2012-10-31     CHI     Bulls           2
6: 2012-10-31     DET   Pistons           2
7: 2012-11-02     BOS   Celtics           3
8: 2012-11-02     MIL     Bucks           3
```

As mentioned by @Mike H., you can also just steal the `rleid` function from `data.table` without converting `df`:

```
df$date_numbers <- data.table::rleid(df$date_game)
```

Another option with Base R:

```
df$date_numbers <- rep(seq_along(unique(df$date_game)), 
                       rle(as.integer(df$date_game))$lengths)
```

Comment: @MikeH. True, either way is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly more esoteric option:

```
mydf$date_numbers <- cumsum(c(1, tail(!(mydf$date_game == lag(mydf$date_game)), - 1)))
```